# Google Maps API: Turn off icons in an array for certain zoom levels

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I have multiple icons in an array with info boxes attached to each that have information for that location.

```
for(var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {
        infomarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            position: markerData[i].latLng,
            visible: true,
            icon: infoicon
        }),
 boxText = document.createElement("div"),
        infoboxOptions = {
            content: boxText,  
etc.......
```

I also have some other symbols that have links to other pages. I managed to remove the other symbols at a certain zoom level

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
 var zoom = map.getZoom();
if (zoom <= 10) {
    louisvillepagemarker.setMap(null);
} else {
    louisvillepagemarker.setMap(map);
}
});
```

I want to remove the icons put on by the array when the map is zoomed out. I played around with several attempts, but I am not succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

create a `MVCObject` with a property `map` .

When you create the Markers bind their `map`-property to the `map`-property of this `MVCObject`.

On `zoom_changed` change only the `map`-property of this `MVCObject` to the desired value, the markers will inherit this property.